# TSQL Subquery Behavior

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

SQL Server [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) don't indicate a requirement for using table aliases in subqueries, or when not used, the expected behavior.  For example:

```
-- create and populate two tables with unique column names
create table tbl1 (col1 int);
insert tbl1 values (1);
create table tbl2 (col2 int);
insert tbl2 values (2);

-- execute query and subquery 
select col1 from tbl1 
    where col1 in (select col1 from tbl2);
```

The subquery alone returns the expected error:

```
Invalid column name 'col1'.
```

But the full query returns a result without raising an error.

[image: query result]

Is this behavior **officially documented** either by Microsoft or SQL-92 standard?  Thanks!

Comment: Over 8 years ago an identical question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110550/why-not-invalid-column-name-xyz-error-in-subquery-although-column-name-is-not) and it appears the answer is still the same: the subquery behavior is undocumented and aliasing is the best workaround

Comment: There is nothing undocumented about it. Every RDBMS will behave this way. It is standard SQL.

Comment: "There is nothing undocumented about it" - can you link to any documentation that addresses my question?

Comment: A subquery creates a nested scope for resolving column names. If the column name cannot be found in the innermost query then outer queries are checked, in order, to resolve the name. As long as a non-ambiguous match is found, i.e. it doesn't come down to joined tables which both (or more) have the same column name, there is no ambiguity or error. The best practice is to always use _meaningful_ table aliases on all column references. (Imagine if one day someone changed/added/removed a column name causing existing queries to shift references to a different table. An error is better.)

Comment: How about Section 5.4.12 in [this](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) vintage standard? (Tip: search for "nested".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the documentation [now addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver16#qualifying) this behavior:

*”If a column is referenced in a subquery that does not exist in the table referenced by the subquery's FROM clause, but exists in a table referenced by the outer query's FROM clause, the query executes without error. SQL Server implicitly qualifies the column in the subquery with the table name in the outer query.”*

Answer (score 2):

It's correlating with tbl1. *Always* alias your tables

This one runs as expected

```
create table tbl1 (col1 int);
insert tbl1 values (1);
create table tbl2 (col2 int);
insert tbl2 values (2);

-- execute query and subquery 
select col1 from tbl1 
    where col1 in (select Z.col1 from tbl2 Z);
```

I know it's irritating and undocumented and seems like a bug but it isn't. If your column name matches *one* column from all of the valid columns in scope, it uses that column. That's what's happening here. There are coding practices that stop these gotchas, i.e. aliasing everything.

I wouldn't call aliasing a workaround. There's no workaround here - it's completely logical.

You could go digging around the definitions for how correlated subqueries work and you would probably find an answer but I would just consider it a lesson learnt.

Comment: Thanks, works yes.  And it was clear that's where the query engine was getting confused.  I should clarify my question -- is the alias requirement documented?

Comment: " the query engine was getting confused" - no, it wasn't. That's how it works.

Comment: "that's how it works" - officially documented where?

Comment: You could dig through definitions of how correlated subqueries work and you would probably find something there but really I wouldn't bother. It's all completely logical and repeatable.

Answer (score 2):

The sub-query reference to column 'col1' is actually referring to the outer table:

```
select col1 from tbl1 
    where col1 in (select col1 from tbl2);
                          ^^^  this is 'col1' in table 'tbl1'
```

This behaves as expected:

```
select t1.col1 from tbl1 t1
    where t1.col1 in (select t2.col1 from tbl2 t2);
```

To avoid unexpected results, always alias your tables.

Comment: Thanks - is the alias advice/requirement documented?

Comment: Sorry, I meant is it officially documented?  Or does the aliasing amount to a workaround?